# How to Iterate ID#s to Pull API JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, dataframe

I am attempting to iterate through a list of Event IDs to pull an API in JSON format. The below code continues to get me a "KeyError: 0" on the last line of the loop that is appending.

I've tried just about everything but can't figure out what's causing the '0' error. I've also pasted the json code below in case that's helpful at all. Thank you in advance if anyone is able to help.

```js
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-394-080fcaba38c8> in <module>
     19 
     20     for x in range(0, 1):
---> 21         all_odds_list.append(dataset_all_json['results'][x])
     22 
     23 

KeyError: 0
```

```html
upcoming_event_ids = ['2302427', '2302543', '2302208', '2112234', '23058244', '2308529', '2302242', '2305045']

all_data_list = []

for id in upcoming_event_ids:
    url = (f'https://api.betsapi.com/v2/event/odds?token=XXTOKENHIDDENXXN&event_id={id}')
    dataset_all = requests.get(url)
    dataset_all_json = dataset_all.json()
    number_of_entries = len(dataset_all_json['results'])

    for x in range(0, number_of_entries):
        all_data_list.append(dataset_all_json['results'][x])
        
upcoming_odds = json_normalize(dataset_all_json)
```

Comment: it's a bit unclear what u r trying to do. could u explain a bit more, share a sample of the json data, and ur expected output

Comment: I'm trying to iterate each id in the "upcoming_event_ids" list, through the url loop to create one consolidated data frame with all of the upcoming event data consolidated.

so the first url to request should be:
https://api.betsapi.com/v2/event/odds?token=XXTOKENHIDDENXXN&event_id=2302427

the second url request should be:
https://api.betsapi.com/v2/event/odds?token=XXTOKENHIDDENXXN&event_id=2302543